# How to stop all chronometers of items in RecyclerView even those ones are hidden? KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, timer, chronometer

I Shared with group to build a Task Timer App, which start timer (stopWatch) when you click on item and when you click again it will stop timer.
I used Android Chronometer for that and put it for each item in recyclerview

**I faced problem when user start a first timer then scroll down the first one will stopped even the user does not stop it.
So I hope to find someone to help me to solve this issue**

Thank you

this is an app
https://github.com/hsn-amr/Task-Timer

this is a recyclerview adapter

```
package com.example.tasktimer

import android.app.Application
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.tasktimer.model.Task
import com.example.tasktimer.viewmodel.TaskViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_row.view.*
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Chronometer
import androidx.core.view.doOnDetach
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.example.tasktimer.fragments.ViewFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_view.view.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

class HomeRecyclerView(application: Application, val viewFragment: ViewFragment):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerView.ItemViewHolder>() {
    class ItemViewHolder( itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private var tasks = emptyList<Task>()
    private val taskViewModel by lazy { TaskViewModel(application) }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        return ItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_row,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        val task = tasks[position]

        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTitleInHome.text = task.task
            chronometer.text = task.timer

            if(task.active){
                chronometer.text = task.timer
                viewFragment.mainTitle.text = task.task
                chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - task.pauseOffset
                chronometer.start()
                chronometer.onChronometerTickListener = Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener { chronometer ->
                    viewFragment.mainTime.text = chronometer.text
                }
            }

            tvTitleInHome.setOnClickListener {

                viewFragment.mainTitle.text = task.task

                if(!task.active){
                    viewFragment.stopAllOtherTimers(viewFragment.tasks, task.id)
                    chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - task.pauseOffset
                    chronometer.start()
                    task.active = true
                    taskViewModel.updateTask(task)
                    viewFragment.showingButtons(false)
                }else{
                    task.timer = chronometer.text.toString()
                    chronometer.stop()
                    task.pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.base
                    task.active = false
                    chronometer.text = task.timer
                    taskViewModel.updateTask(task)
                    viewFragment.showingButtons(true)
                }

                chronometer.onChronometerTickListener = Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener { chronometer ->
                    viewFragment.mainTime.text = chronometer.text
                }

                viewFragment.pauseButton.setOnClickListener {
                    pauseTimer(task, chronometer)
                }

                viewFragment.restartButton.setOnClickListener {
                    restartTimer(task, chronometer)
                }
            }
        }

    }


    fun pauseTimer(task: Task, chronometer: Chronometer){
        chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - task.pauseOffset
        chronometer.start()
        task.active = true
        taskViewModel.updateTask(task)
        viewFragment.showingButtons(false)
    }

    fun restartTimer(task:Task, chronometer: Chronometer){
        task.totalTime = getTotalFromString(task.totalTime, chronometer.text.toString())
        chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        task.pauseOffset = 0
        chronometer.start()
        task.active = true
        taskViewModel.updateTask(task)
        viewFragment.showingButtons(false)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = tasks.size

    fun update(tasks: List<Task>){
        this.tasks = tasks
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun getTotalFromString(oldString:String, newString: String): String {
        var oldHours = 0
        var oldMinutes = 0
        var oldSeconds = 0
        val oldStringArray = oldString.split(":")
        if(oldStringArray.size == 2){
            oldMinutes = oldStringArray[0].toInt()
            oldSeconds = oldStringArray[1].toInt()
        }else{
            oldHours = oldStringArray[0].toInt()
            oldMinutes = oldStringArray[1].toInt()
            oldSeconds = oldStringArray[2].toInt()
        }

        var newHours = 0
        var newMinutes = 0
        var newSeconds = 0
        val newStringArray = newString.split(":")
        if(newStringArray.size == 2){
            newMinutes = newStringArray[0].toInt() + oldMinutes
            newSeconds = newStringArray[1].toInt() + oldSeconds
        }else{
            newHours = newStringArray[0].toInt() + oldHours
            newMinutes = newStringArray[1].toInt() + oldMinutes
            newSeconds = newStringArray[2].toInt() + oldSeconds
        }

        if(newSeconds>=60){
            newMinutes += newSeconds/60
            newSeconds %= 60
        }
        if(newMinutes>=60){
            newHours += newMinutes/60
            newMinutes %= 60
        }

        val result = (if (newHours < 10) "0$newHours" else newHours).toString() +
                ":" + (if (newMinutes < 10) "0$newMinutes" else newMinutes) +
                ":" + if (newSeconds < 10) "0$newSeconds" else newSeconds

        return result
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to realize that `ViewHolder`s are volatile and they get recycled/reused between different positions and not all items will have a viewholder that displays it (unless your list is really short but it's best not to assume that). They are only representing your data set and should never perform operations that alter it (aside from accepting user input). Your tasks and elapsed time should run entirely within view model that's unaffected by actual view state, relying on chronometer widgets ticks to emit updates is a design error.

Comment: First I would like to thank you to your comment. Second, in your opinion what is a solution? in other word, which tool should I use to this situation to stop all chronometers and also to keep some chronometers work even after they hide.